# Using regex, how to replace the text NOT included in specific html tag?

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have this text:

```
The quick brown fox <a href="http://www.example1.com">jumps over</a> the <a href="http://www.example2.com">lazy</a> dog
```

How can I replace all the characters, say, to X except those between the <a> tag? In the above example I would like to get:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<a href="http://www.example1.com">jumps over</a>XXXX<a href="http://www.example2.com">lazy</a>XXXX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern which will find each single characters not between `<a>` tags:

```
(?:\G|(?<=</a>))(?:[^<]|<(?!a\b))
```

**pattern explanation:**

```
(?:            # open a non capturing group
    \G         # contiguous to precedent match or the begining of the string
  |            # OR
    (?<=</a>)  # preceded by the closing "a" tags
)              # close the non capturing group
(?:            # open a non capturing group
    [^<]       # all that is not a <
  |            # OR
    <(?!a\b)   # < not followed by "a" (=not a "a" tag)
)              # close the non capturing group
```

**Notice:** Newlines would be replaced by two `X` (one for `\r` and one for `\n`). If you want to avoid this behavior, you can change the pattern to:

```
(?:\G|(?<=</a>))(?:\r\n|[^<]|<(?!a\b))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn’t know about \G  Why do you need to open a non capturing group? A capturing group would work as well, wouldn'it?

Comment: @Anthony: indeed, you can do the same with a capturing group, but since you don't need to capture anything, a non-capturing group avoid to use memory for nothing.

Comment: @Anthony: In the same way, you can replace non-capturing groups by atomic groups `(?>...)` since the regex engine doesn't need to record backtrack positions.